# Parsing JSON data and display it as a table

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, parsing

1. How do I to get the first timestamp value off of the first row using C# and Newtonsoft.Json?
2. How do I display this data in a table with headers *beaId*, *bfiId*, *timestamp*, *beaName*, *bfiName* using AngularJS?

```js
{
  "deviceId": "141646166286414",
  "data": {
    "65473": {
      "beaId": "141646166286414",
      "bfiId": 65473,
      "rssi": -94,
      "temp": 20.25,
      "battery": 3660,
      "timestamp": 1650558413362,
      "status": "CONNECTED",
      "beaName": "",
      "bfiName": "RO-EI-05:312_AC",
      "channel": 39
    },
    "65185": {
      "beaId": "141646166286414",
      "bfiId": 65185,
      "rssi": -94,
      "temp": 20.25,
      "battery": 3660,
      "timestamp": 1650558433304,
      "status": "CONNECTED",
      "beaName": "",
      "bfiName": "RO-CI-01:309_AC",
      "channel": 39
    },
    "65059": {
      "beaId": "141646166286414",
      "bfiId": 65059,
      "rssi": -92,
      "temp": 20.25,
      "battery": 3660,
      "timestamp": 1650558393482,
      "status": "CONNECTED",
      "beaName": "",
      "bfiName": "RO-EI-09:399_AC",
      "channel": 39
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I have tried. Let me know if this is the correct way to get the first timestamp value from the JSON string.

```
var beaInfo = JObject.Parse("<Above Json string>");                    
var sdmap = beaInfo["data"];
var tmStamp = sdmap.First.First["timestamp"];
```

TIA

Comment: What have you tried so far? And please format the description of your question. It is quite unclear.

Comment: I need to display this  "timestamp: 1650558413362" but not sure how to parse the JSON data to get this value.

Comment: Have you tried parsing using [Newtonsoft.Json library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 1):

*Regarding the C# json parsing question:*

The code you posted is correct.

And looks like you already use `Newtonsoft.Json`. In your code `tmStamp` will be of type `JToken` and will hold the integer value of `1650558413362`.

Some explanations about using Newtonsoft.Json:

As you probably know json is a tree-like structure.
`beaInfo` is a `JObject` holding the entire json structure.
`sdmap` is a `JToken` and holds the sub tree "data".
`First` returns a `JToken` of the first child of a given node.
Using it twice will get `tmStamp` to be the `JToken` refering to the node that you need.

You can verify that `tmStamp` indeed refers to the first timestamp you can use:

```
Console.WriteLine("timestamp: " + tmStamp.ToString());
```

*Regarding the AngularJS question:*

I recomend to post it as a separate question. It is prefered in StackOverflow (and related sites) that each post will contain only 1 question. See here: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 0):

You have to deserialise the JSON and than to operate with it. In C# you have build in functions to do this. [deserialise JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm)